# Evaluating Hankel and Bessel Function

Tags: integration

please I need help in evaluating this integral

$$
\int_{0}^{z}yH_{n}(y)J_{n}(y)dy
$$
where $H_{n}(y)$ is the Hankel function and $J_{n}(y)$ is Bessel function.

The first thing that came to mind was applying the derivative identity
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}[y^{n}J_{n}(y)] = y^{n}J_{n-1}(y)
$$
to the integral and using integration by part to solve it. Please any solution or idea will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Not an actual answer, bur Wolfram says 
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2in\,_1F_2\left(-\frac{1}{2};-n,n;-z^2\right)}{\pi}+\left(z^2-i\left(4n^2-z^2\right)\cot(\pi n)\right)J_n(z){}^2+z^2J_{n-1}(z){}^2+iz^2\cot(\pi n)J_{n+1}(z){}^2+2inz(\cot(\pi n)+i)J_n(z)J_{n-1}(z)-\frac{2in}{\pi}\right)
$$

Comment: @caverac lol that's one long answer